# Scriplet stops website from starting

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags, scriptlet

i have a scriplet on my index.jsp, what the scriplet should do is get the info from "session.getAttribute" and display on the div, but index.jsp should still run even if no user is logged in

heres the scriplet

```
<div class="templatemo_content_left_section">
40:  <h1>Bem Vindo</h1>

40:  <%= session.getAttribute("currentSessionUser")%>
41:   <%if (session.getAttribute("currentSessionUser").equals("")){%>
42: <a href="Login.jsp"><b>Login</b></a>
43:<%}
44: else{%>
45:<a href="logout.jsp"><b>Logout</b></a>
46:<%
47:}
48:%>
```

the log i get says the error "message An exception occurred processing JSP page /Index.jsp at line 43"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`session.getAttribute()` returns null if the attribute doesn't exist. That's [documented explicitely](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29). So obviously, if you call `equals()` on the result, you'll get a NUllPointerException. Compare the result to null instead:

```
 <%if (session.getAttribute("currentSessionUser") == null)
```

Or even better, use the JSP EL and the JSTL. Scriptlets should be avoided:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${empty sessionScope.currentSessionUser}">
        <a href="Login.jsp"><b>Login</b></a>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise> 
        <a href="logout.jsp"><b>Logout</b></a>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Bad school still teaching old ways, but now i have another problem, what it returns is "login.UserBean@5b42b86d" and not the username, have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: That means you have an object of type login.UserBean stored in this session attribute. Get the name from this object: `UserBean userBean = (UserBean) session.getAttribute("currentSessionUser"); String userName = userBean.getName();`. It would be much easier with the EL: `${sessionScope.currentSessionUser.name}`. Kindly ask your teachers to teach you things that are not obsolete for more than 12 years.

Comment: Of course. All Java code in a JSP must be inside scriptlets. But there should be no Java code at all in JSPs in a well-designed application.

Comment: I will talk to my teachers so that they update themselves, because as far as i can tell they don´t even work on the programing business.Thank you very much for your help

Comment: I'm sorry i tested the your code and it validates ok but doesn't show the username, what tag do i use to show it?

Comment: `out.println(userName);` or `<%= userName %>`. Re-read your text. Writing something to the response is really basic stuff that is probably explained in the first parts of the section about JSPs and scriptlets.

Comment: i solved it with <p>Welcome, <c:out value="${currentSessionUser.username}" /></p>, won't bother you again, thank you very much for the help you gave me ;)